# How to declare extern typedef struct?

Tags: c, extern

I have two c files, foo.c with the functionality and test_foo.c which test the functions of foo.c.

Is there a way to access the struct typedef `BAR` I defined in foo.c in test_foo.c without using a header file? So far, I was able to avoid a h file so that the whole program would consist of foo.c. Thanks.

```
foo.c   
typedef struct BAR_{...} bar;
BAR *bar_new(...) {..}

test_foo.c
extern BAR *bar_new(...)
```

`error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘BAR’`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is that there is one, and you should use an header file instead.
You can copy the definition of the struct `typedef struct BAR_{...} bar;` into `test_foo.c` and it will work. But this causes duplication.
Every solution that works must make the implementation of struct available to the compiler in `test_foo.c`.
You may also use an ADT if this suits you in this case.

Comment: Moving the definition to the header file is the right solution only if test_foo.c (or any other modules outside of foo.c) needs to access the contents struct itself. If it's an ADT or for some other reason test_foo.c don't need the internals of the type, I think a forward declaration is a better solution.

Comment: For now, I just copied the definition into the other c file.

Comment: I am doing the same - I am developing a test harness that is supposed to wrap around production code. In the production code the structure definition has no business being public and should be buried. Therefore I had to copy the definition into my test harness. This is duplication but my linker is smart enough to give me warnings if one changes but not the other.

Answer (score 4):

Drop the typedef.

In foo.c:

```
struct bar 
{
    ...
};

struct bar *bar_new(....)
{
    return malloc(sizeof(struct bar));
}
```

In test_foo.c:

```
struct bar;

struct bar *mybar = bar_new(...);
```

Note that you only get the existence of a struct bar object in this way, the user in test_foo.c does not know anything about the contents of the object.

Comment: You might as well keep the typedef and just cast it to void in foo.c then.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to supply the definition of BAR in test_foo.c. Whether that duplication is preferable to having a header is up to you.