# Extern typedefs in C

Tags: c, include, typedef

I have 4 files:

a.h:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} A;
```

b.h:

```
#include "a.h"
typedef struct {
    A a;
    int b;
} B;
```

c.h:

```
#include "a.h"
typedef struct {
    A a;
    double c;
} C;
```

d.c:

```
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
//Here I want to use types A, B and C
```

int and double are only examples, the real problem I have is far more complex.
The point is that it should be possible to convert types B and C to A by simply casting to it.
The issue I´m fighting is that it says type A is included multiple times, which is comprehensible because d.c includes b.h which includes a.h, but a.h is also included by c.h.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You're looking for "include guards".

Comment: casting the *values*? Not unless you're fond of slicing. You may want to consider using include guards, as you don't appear to have a circular reference, so this should be resolvable without gimickery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare extern typedef struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227654/how-to-declare-extern-typedef-struct)

Comment: No, I´ve read the question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227654/how-to-declare-extern-typedef-struct but could not really figure out how to implement this in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H_INCLUDED
#define A_H_INCLUDED
typedef struct {
    int a;
} A;
#endif
```

b.h

```
#ifndef B_H_INCLUDED
#define B_H_INCLUDED
#include "a.h"
typedef struct {
    A a;
    int b;
} B;
#endif
```

c.h

```
#ifndef C_H_INCLUDED
#define C_H_INCLUDED
#include "a.h"
typedef struct {
    A a;
    double c;
} C;
#endif
```

d.c

```
#include "a.h" // if you're going to use type A specifically do #include the proper file
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
//Here I want to use types A, B and C
```

Answer (score 3):

Use include guards, like so:

```
#ifndef A_INCLUDED
#define A_INCLUDED
typedef struct {
  int a;
} A;
#endif
```

in each of your .h file, with unique guard names per file

Comment: Thanks for the answers. What does this ifndef, define and endif exactly do? (I googled but I did not really found an answer...) Edit: Oh, so stupid - found on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard; Thanks for all your help!!!